# optional match not returning result

Tags: node.js, neo4j

when I fire this query in neo4j browser (localhost:7474/browser)

```
match (s:Song)
optional match (sg:SongGroup)-[r:SONGGROUP_SONG]->(s) where id(sg) = 294
return sg.title , s.title
```

...I get this: (both sg.title and s.title have data)

```
sg.title    s.title
test 3      Shake it off
....        .....
```

when I push the same query into this function in nodejs (using npm request module):

```
function cypherQuery(query, params, callback) {
  request.post({
      uri    : 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher',
      json   : {query: query, params: params}
    },
    function(err, res, body) {
      callback(err, body);
    });
```

...I get this: (only s.title has data)

```
{ columns: [ 's.title', 'sg.title' ],
  data: 
   [ [ 'My forbidden lover', null ],
     [ 'Step back', null ],
     [ 'Shake it off', null ],
     [ 'Two Hearts', null ],
     [ 'Homelands', null ] ] }
```

I've tried the same with modules neo4j-node and seraph, both giving me the same results (sg.title = null)

However, when I use Postman, everything works again.

POST localhost:7474/db/data/cypher
with body (raw) set to

```
{
  "query" : "match (s:Song) optional match (sg:SongGroup)-[r:SONGGROUP_SONG]->(s) where id(sg) = {recId} return s.title, sg.title ",
  "params" : {"recId": 294}

}
```

Any idea why this works in browser and postman, but not in node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse `recId` so that it is an integer, not a string. (note that the information required to reach this conclusion is not included on this page, but it is on [this one](https://github.com/brikteknologier/seraph/issues/179#issuecomment-141769509).

When you parse it as a string, cypher tries to compare equality of `id(sg)` and `"294"`, one being an integer and another a string. Works in JS, but not in Cypher.

Comment: to clearify a bit more: I wasn't using parseInt() in the params object. 
var params = {recId: parseInt(req.params.recId)};  (saved the weekend)